# Firebase init fails with Error: codebase source must be specified

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase

Firebase init functions gives this error:

Error: codebase source must be specified

I deleted the functions directory as I wanted to switch back to javascript from typescript.
I expected to be able to delete and use firebase init to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the entry for functions in firebase.json in the firebase directory then run `Firebase init functions`